# Login using Tinder API

Tags: ios, objective-c, tinder

I am using https://gist.github.com/rtt/10403467 for reference but I am not able to login into Tinder. I get a blank response.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.gotinder.com/auth"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

//NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"facebook_token\": %@, \"facebook_id\": %@}",accessToken,userID];
NSDictionary *dataDict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:accessToken, @"facebook_token", userID, @"facebook_id", nil];
NSData *dataFromDict = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dataDict
                                                       options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments
                                                         error:nil];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
//[request setHTTPBody:[str dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:dataFromDict];
[request setValue:@"Tinder/4.1.4 (iPhone; iOS 9.3; Scale/2.00)" forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];
[request setValue:@"ios" forHTTPHeaderField:@"platform"];
[request setValue:@"1.0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"app-version"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",[dataFromDict length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                              delegate:self];
[connection start];
```

Please help

Comment: "blank"?  Completely empty?  No error code?  No calls on the delegate?

Comment: @Droppy - delegate methods of NSURLConnection are called but there is not response data.

Comment: Am I sending the facebookToken and Facebook_id in the correct way?